# Permutations of Objects on Grid

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to visualize all possible permutations of 12 objects in a 7x7 grid.

Firstly, I would like to find out how many there are. And secondly, how can I visualize all of them?

Comment: Are the twelve objects distinguishable or indistinguishable?  I.e., If we swap two of them in a configuration, do we get the same or a different configuration?

Comment: They are the indistinguishable.

Comment: So the answer should simply be $49\choose 12$, shouldn't it?

Comment: I am basically trying to find all the versions of the European flag. I have simplified it into this grid for the first stage. At a later point I would like to see those little stars randomly distributed over the surface without overlapping. But that is for a later problem.

Comment: The problem is more interesting if we identify (count only once) the rotations and/or reflections (symmetries) of possible arrangements.  Some selections of twelve are already their own rotations and reflections, while others can have up to eight in their orbits (under the dihedral group action).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $92\ 263\ 734\ 836$, which is over ten thousand more times the number of steps you would have to take in order to walk to the moon.

The [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) are the relevant numbers here. Specifically, the symbol $n\choose m$, read "$n$ choose $m$", represents the number of ways to select $m$ objects out of a set of $n$ objects. So here you need to select $12$ objects out of a set of $49$ (the $49$ objects are the grid points, and you need to choose $12$ of them), so the answer is $49\choose 12$. There are many methods for calculating a binoomial coefficient, one of which is to type "$49$ choose $12$" into Google.

I don't know what you mean by "visualizing" all of the permutations.

Comment: Well, I will just have to make 92 263 734 836 drawings. Yay. Thanks for you help.